# Mostrar imagen mientras se procesa formulario

Tags: php, jquery

Desde un formulario se envía dos valores:

```
<form action="accion.php" method="post">
 <p>Su nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" /></p>
 <p>Su edad: <input type="text" name="edad" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

En el archivo PHP se realizan varios procesos que tardan un tiempo en procesar:

```
$Master = new Maestro();

//----- PROCESOS
$cruzarCodigos = $Master->cruzarCodigos($_POST['nombre'], $_POST['edad']);
$cruzarNombres = $Master->cruzarNombres();
$cruzarFechas  = $Master->cruzarFechas();
$calcularSueldos = $Master->calcularSueldos();
//----- MOSTRAR MENSAJE
$tpl = new Plantilla();
$tpl->assign('mensaje', 'PROCESO TERMINADO');
$tpl->display('procesado.tpl.php');
```

Y en la plantilla Smarty se muestra un mensaje luego de terminado el proceso.

```
<h5>{$mensaje}</h5>
```

Desde que se da click en el botón ***Submit*** hasta que muestra el **$mensaje** la pantalla queda congelada todo el tiempo que tarda en procesar todos los procesos.
Cómo puedo mostrar una imagen luego de dar click a ***Submit*** y que desaparezca al mostrar el mensaje?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  **Con este codigo de css y el script de jquery mostraras un gift de tu elección que represente la carga de la página, el div con la clase loader lo pones debajo de la etique de apertura del body. Espero te sirva**
```

```js
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
       
        $(window).load(function() {
        $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
    });
    </script>
```

```css
<style>
          
    
    .loader {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: url('images/uploading.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
        opacity: .8;
    }
        </style>
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```